# Check indexes against lists with indexes

Tags: python

If I have a list of lists in Python, and I make lists from parts of that list of lists, how could I check which list an index were in.

For example:

```
LOL = [
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 1, 8],
    [6, 2, 9]
    ]
list1 = [LOL[0][0], LOL[0][1], LOL[1][1]]
list2 = [LOL[2][2], LOL[2][1], LOL[1][2]]
list3 = [LOL[2][0], LOL[1][2], LOL[0][2]]
```

(These indices are completely intentional.) The 1 in this list of lists (LOL) is at index `LOL[1][1]` (1,1). How would I check which out of the three lists: list1, list2, and/or list3, it is in?

```
if 1 in row for row in LOL:
    (search the list that the 1 is in for 6. The integers contained in the lists in LOL are just examples, there could be multiple 1's in the lists in LOL.)
```

If there was actual Python Syntax inside the parenthesis that would accomplish the described task, list1 would be searched and because there aren't any 6's in that list the if statement would fall through. How would I fill in the part in parenthesis so that it had the correct Python syntax to accomplish the task described there?

Comment: here is my reversed order floats list  `ROFL = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0][::-1]`

Comment: @cbbcbail LOL lacks the commas between sublists

Comment: @cbbcbail are you trying to find whether '1' is in list1, list2 or list3, and at what index? Or are you asking in which of the 3 lists within LOL is the '1', and which index in that list? Or are you asking what is row/column at which '1' is found in LOL?

Comment: @Schollii Should all be in my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

There are two many issues with the question, and too many comments, so I'm putting the following in an answer:

Firstly, in

> ```
> list1 = [LOL[0][0], LOL[0][1], LOL[1][1]] 
> list2 = [LOL[2][2], LOL[2][1], LOL[1][2]] 
> list3 = [LOL[2][0], LOL[1][2], LOL[0][2]]
> ```

Are the indices correct? Or should they be

```
  list1 = [LOL[0][0], LOL[0][1], LOL[0][2]] 
  list2 = [LOL[1][0], LOL[1][1], LOL[1][2]] 
  list3 = [LOL[2][0], LOL[2][1], LOL[2][2]]
```

Secondly,

> The one in this list of lists is at index LOL[1][1].

This statement does not make sense. By 'one' you are referring to '1', which is at 'index' (1,1) in the sense that LOL[1][1] contains '1'. LOL[1][1] is not an index, it is a value (in fact, it refers to a value).

> How would I check which list it is in?

Which list are you talking about? The list1, list2 or list3 (ie, find in which of those 3 the '1' is referenced), or LOL[0], LOL[1], LOL[2] (ie find in which 'row' is '1' referenced)? Because LOL contains 3 items, each one a list (of integers). LOL does not contain any integers (the items in LOL contain integers).

For this reason,

> if 1 in LOL:

is not valid Python: LOL does not contain any integers. It does make sense if it is pseudocode.

Another issue:

> (search the list that the 1 is in for 0.

0 is not in any list, this is confusing, is it a typo?

> LOL is just an example there could be multiple ones.)

Multiple LOL? How is the fact that there are multiple LOL relevant to the task of finding something in LOL? Or perhaps what you really have is this:

```
  list1 = [LOL2[1][2], LOL1[0][2], LOL3[2][2]]
  list2 = [LOL2[1][2], LOL2[0][2], LOL0[2][2]]
  list3 = [LOL1[1][2], LOL0[0][2], LOL3[0][2]]
```

where I picked the LOL0/1/2/3 randomly as an example. In this case what you are trying to solve is, if you find that '1' is in LOL2, at what (row, col) index is it in LOL2? The row col will satsify LOL2[row][col] is '1'. But this doesn't make much sense to me either.

Finally, if you could provide an example answer like "and the answer would be list2" or "and the answer would be LOL[1]", that can help a lot with understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Please clarify your post with all of the above to minimize how much back and forth commenting occurs, there is a huge amount of noise right now and I'm really tempted to flag the question for closure so you can start from scratch (I feel it is a good question so I hope to see it through).

Comment: I am editing my question so that it answers all of your questions. Thanks for the answer. I realize that I have not been clear enough, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The list1, 2 and 3 do not contain references to the numbers in the LOL. Consider this:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ll=[1,2,3]
>>> kk=[ll[1], ll[0], ll[2]]
>>> kk
[2, 1, 3]
>>> ll[2]=5
>>> kk
[2, 1, 3]
>>>
```

So the code you show, once executed, causes the following to be in Python interpreter:

```
LOL = [
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 1, 8],
    [6, 2, 9]
    ]
list1 = [4, 5, 1]
list2 = [9, 2, 8]
list3 = [6, 8, 6]
```

Ie, there are no references to numbers, just the numbers themselves.

Since 1 is unique you could find by element search which list1/2/3 it is in, but for a number like 8, there would be two answers (list2 and list3). Also, there is no way of knowing, as shown in my first code sample, which LOL item the number corresponds to: is list3[0] the LOL[0][2] or the LOL[2][0]? There is no way of knowing.

OTOH, if you store objects in your LOL lists instead of numbers, you can find them by reference. Consider this code:

```
>>> a,b,c=[0],[1],[2]
>>> ll=[a,b,c]
>>> ll
[[0], [1], [2]]
>>> a[0]=5
>>> ll
[[5], [1], [2]]
>>>
```

This shows that ll is storing references to a, b, c, because those are themselves objects.

Then it is possible to find which of a,b,c contains a given number, and to find where the number is specifically in ll:

```
if 2 in a: 
   return ll.index(a)
if 2 in b: 
   return ll.index(b)
if 2 in c: 
   return ll.index(c)
```

Given the above, I suspect the answer is that you cannot get what you are looking for, unless you rewrite your LOL and 3 lists to contain objects, like this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,...=[0],[1],[2],[4],[2],[6],...
LOL=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]
list1=[a,c,f]
list2=[d,a,b]
list3=[f,g,a]
```

Then if you are looking for c, which has same number as e but is a different object, you would do

```
index = getIndex(c[0], list1)
if index >= 0:
    return getLOLItem(list1[index])
```

where

```
def getLOLItem(item):
    for subLOL in LOL: 
       if item in subLOL:
          return subLOL.index(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if 1 in some_list:
   ...
```

As for how to check the different variables, don't. Put them in a list or dict instead.

Comment: No, Im sorry if I didn't make it clear enough. I want to check if the index of the one is there.

Comment: "check if the index of the one is there" makes even less sense.

Comment: One has the index of LOL[1][1]. correct? in which list is this index contained?

Comment: `list1` has no knowledge of the index from where the contents came from.  you can however check if `LOL[1][1] in list1`.

Comment: How would I say index of 1. If, say I didn't know what the index of 1 was. I want to say: if index of 1 is in list1: Except with the actual Python Syntax

Comment: Again, objects don't know where they come from.

Comment: But the list doesn't need to know does it? If I were to do LOL.index(1) that would give me the index of 1 right? so if I could find which list LOL.index(1) was in it would essentially be the same thing. How would I use that?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I have looked at all of what I have written. Why do you say that? I am trying to learn Python. is what I said in my previous comment valid?

Comment: You need to look again at `list1`, `list2`, and `list3`.

Comment: list1, list2, and list3 contain indexes that refer to integers in LOL.

Comment: They are the same thing in this instance.

Comment: They do not have indexes in them.

Comment: @cbbcbail You are completely confused. You lack rigour.

Comment: @cbbcbail _"The one in this list of lists is at index LOL[1][1]."_ NO, LOL[1][1] isn't an index , it is the number 1.

Comment: @cbbcbail You write everywhere : _"index of 1"_ But it has no sense. There is no absolute index, an index is always relatively to a precised container (list, tuple...)  What do you mean when you allude to the index of 1 ??

Comment: When I am talking about the index of 1 I mean the place in the list that 1 is located

Comment: @cbbcbail _" the place in the list that 1 is located"_ Which list ? LOL ? You need to know the index of the sublist in LOL in which sublist 1 is contained ? - By the way, though english isn't my natural language, I think it should be written _"the place in the list WHERE 1 is located"_

Comment: LOL. In a list of lists you would use LOL[1][1] to find the first row first column in that list of lists.

Comment: @cbbcbail And then ? What am I supposed to understand ?

Comment: That is how you would locate 1 in a list of lists

Comment: @cbbcbail Interesting. And what do you want ? You want a function that returns the tuple (1,1) when you pass it the number 1 ? And returns (3,1) when you pass 6 ? Say what you want, if even you know it

Comment: @cbbcbail Well, I didn't take enough attention to the fact that there are two numbers 6 in the sublists in LOL. What do you want to obtain in this case ?

Comment: Read my question it says quite clearly: if 1 in LOL:
    (search the list that the 1 is in for 0. LOL is just an example there could be multiple ones.) How would

Comment: @cbbcbail I begin to understand: you use the word "index" in an erroneous sense. "index" doesn't mean location or position or something like that. In Python, it designates a precise thing: please refer to the doc to understand what it designates. And you should make effort to employ words in the sense they are employed in Python, not with a lack of rigour that makes you think that you are allowed to employ words with crazy meanings while being still understood by others. That's incredible. You have still some cheeks to say _"my question says it clearly"_

Comment: @cbbcbail ``if 1 in LOL:`` will give False until the end of times, because LOL doesn't contain numbers but sublists

Comment: @cbbcbail _"search the list that the 1 is in for 0"_ What does the **"for 0"** mean ???

Comment: if 1 in row for row in LOL: for 0 means for 0 it is simple as that. It will search for 0 in the list that the 1 is in.

Answer (score 0):

```
val = 1
for i, lst in enumerate(LOL):
    if val in lst:
        print(i, lst.index(val))
```

will print "1, 1".

Comment: How would I say index of 1. If, say I didn't know what the index of 1 was. I want to say: if index of 1 is in list1: Except with the actual Python Syntax

Comment: man, you just aren't getting it .. you never put the index of 1 into `list1`, you put the object 1 into it

Comment: OK, then. If I can't look for the indexes in the lists. How would I do this. See edits to question.

Comment: @jnnnnn Did you read my question? This isn't what I am trying to do.

Comment: the index(value) function of a list object returns the index of the specified value in the list. Is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is confusion in the use of "index" here.  I'll take a stab at it.  This will return the name of the sublist and the index within the sublist.  I think others have shown how to find the index in the original LOL.

```
LOL = [
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 1, 8],
    [6, 2, 9],
    ] 

#store the sublists in a dictionary
checkLists = {
    'list1':[LOL[0][0], LOL[0][1], LOL[1][1]],
    'list2':[LOL[2][2], LOL[2][1], LOL[1][2]],
    'list3':[LOL[2][0], LOL[1][2], LOL[0][2]] 
    }

#the value you are looking for
checkVal = 1

#recursive function to search for a value in a list of lists
def containsValue(val,items):
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item,(list,tuple)):
            if find(val,item):
                return True
        else:
            print item
            if item == val:
                return True
    return False

#Now check to see if and where the checkVal exists in the sublists
if containsValue(checkVal, LOL):
    #search each sublist for the checkVal
    for k,v in checkLists.items():
        #see if the value is in the sublist
        if checkVal in v:
            #return the sublist key and index where we found the value
            i = v.index(checkVal)
            return (k,i)
```

Comment: So you are basically making with list 1, list 2, and list 3 and checking if 1 is in the entire thing? What exactly does 'k' do?

Comment: @tharen How can you test ``if checkval in LOL:`` with checkval having value 1 since the content of LOL is several LISTS, not numbers !!!!

Comment: @cbbcbail k is dictionary key, v is the sublist.  k is the name fo the sublist.

Comment: @eyquem Good point.  I glossed over that one.  I added simple recursive function to test if the value is in the original LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
LOL = [[4, 5, 6],
       [7, 1, 8],
       [6, 2, 9] ]

list1 = [LOL[0][0], LOL[0][1], LOL[1][1]]
list2 = [LOL[2][2], LOL[2][1], LOL[1][2]]
list3 = [LOL[2][0], LOL[1][2], LOL[0][2]]


def sublist_index_of_li_in_which_is_x(li,x):
    return (i for i,sublist in enumerate(li) if x in sublist).next()


print sublist_index_of_li_in_which_is_x(LOL,1)
print sublist_index_of_li_in_which_is_x(LOL,9)
```

return

```
1
2
```

Maybe.

By the way, what list1,list2,list3 are playing here ?

### EDIT

```
def rowcol_tuples_locating_x_in_li(li,x):
    return [(i,sublist.index(x)) for i,sublist in enumerate(li) if x in sublist]


print rowcol_tuples_locating_x_in_li(LOL,1)
print rowcol_tuples_locating_x_in_li(LOL,6)
```

result

```
[(1, 1)]
[(0, 2), (2, 0)]
```