# Python: Check an index against multiple other indexes

Tags: python

I am using Python and I would like to check the location of a value in a list of lists against other indexes.

Like if I had 1 at (1, 1) I would want to be able to check if 1 were at the other indexes so I could make something happen based on which index it matched.

For example:

```
list_of_lists = [
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 1, 8],
    [6, 2, 9]
    ]
if 1 in row for row in list_of_lists:
    if index of 1 is (0, 0), (0, 1), or (0, 2)
        print ("It is in the First row!")
    if index of 1 is (1, 0), (1, 1), or (1, 2)
        print ("It is in the second row!")
```

If this worked correctly it should print: "It is in the second row!" Because the index of 1 matches with one of the indices in the  third if statement. They may not necessarily be rows in some instances where I would be using this. So If you could provide a way that would not use the rows in your answer. Just a way to look at indexes and compare them. Obviously this is not the correct syntax. But how would I do that in Python? How would I get the index of 1 and compare it to other indexes in a list of lists?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question would be a lot clearer if you explained it in terms of a function. For example, do you want a function that would let you do: `list_index(list_of_lists, 1)` and get (1, 1)? That looks like what you're trying to do, but you keep mentioning 0, and I don't know what that means in this context

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check indexes against lists with indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783148/check-indexes-against-lists-with-indexes)

Comment: @wim Sorry but I didn't seem to be getting anything there and I decided to restate my question and go from a different viewpoint. It seems to have worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trying this in a python file:

```
list_of_lists = [
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 0, 8],
    [6, 2, 9]
]

def index_of(value, matrix):
    for i, r in enumerate(matrix):
        for j, c in enumerate(r):
            if c == value:
                # returns the first instance
                return (i,j)
    return None

if index_of(0, list_of_lists) == (1,1):
    print "hey"

list_of_lists2 = [
    [0, 5, 6],
    [7, 0, 8],
    [0, 2, 9]
]

def indexes_of(value, matrix):
    return [(i,j) for i, r in enumerate(matrix) for j, c in enumerate(r) if c == value]

print indexes_of(0, list_of_lists2)
```

outputs

```
hey
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
```

[**EDIT**] As requested:

First of all, what does enumerate do?

```
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
>>> list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
[(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
```

[source](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate)

As you can see, if you use enumerate, it will return both the index of the element AND the element. Therefore, while you're iterating over the returned list you can access them and do what you desire. That's what I'm doing here:

```
for i, r in enumerate(matrix)
```

In that case, i stands for the row index, and r stands for row itself. ok?

In the next line you do the same thing, but now you're enumerating the row itself, ok? And you're getting, now, the indexes of the values j and the values c that are stored in each row.

Finally, when you return (i,j), you're just returning a tuple that represents the values's matrix index.

Comment: Thanks I think this will really help!

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which part is bothering you?

Comment: Nothing is really bothering me per say. But I would like a bit of an explanation on the confusing part where their are lots of letters. This part: def index_of(value, matrix):
    for i, r in enumerate(matrix):
        for j, c in enumerate(r):
            if c == value:
                # returns the first instance
                return (i,j)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
def lindex(list_of_lists, item):
    for l in list_of_lists:
        if item in l:
            return list_of_lists.index(l)

listoflists = [[4, 5, 6], [7, 1, 8], [6, 2, 9]]
item = 1
print "it is in the %. row" % lindex(listoflists, item)
```

As for your attempt to shortcut with:

```
if 1 in row for row in list_of_lists:
```

1. The syntax is incorrect!
2. You can't avoid to look into every item of every row of the list - NO shortcut
3. For a halway valid compromise to 1. you could try something like:

   rows = [i for i in listoflists if 1 in i]

This would at either give you an empty list, meaning there are no items with the value "1" or a list the rows containing "1"!

You could then print all row-indices containing 1 with:

```
for row in rows:
    print "it is in the %. row" % listoflists.index(row)
```

Comment: There are some instances where the different indexes I am checking would not be in rows. How would I do it in a way were it would not be looking at the rows?

Comment: YOu can't check whether an index is in a row or not without looking...do you have some prior information that allows you to know beforehand when a value is not in `list_of_lists`?

Comment: At the beginning of my "code" I have "if 1 in row for row in list_of_lists:" This should check if it is in list_of_lists.

Comment: That doesn't work! There is no magic. Every item in every row must be checked to verify the existence of a single item. There is no shortcut! How should such a magical feat be done? As long as you don't look schroedinger's cat is dead AND alive!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
>>> for lst in range(len(list_of_lists)):
...     if 1 in list_of_lists[lst]:
...             print "it's in list:", lst
... 
it's in list: 1
>>>
```

remember the `in` operator tests whether a value appears in a list (or list like object).

Here's a second way using the `index` method (discussed in the comments);

```
>>> for lst in range(len(list_of_lists)):
...     try:
...             _ = list_of_lists[lst].index(1)
...             print "1 is in list", lst
...     except ValueError:
...             continue
... 
1 is in list 1
>>>
```

Comment: How could I use this if I didn't always want to check if they were in rows?

Comment: You mean, without using `in`? Several ways, you could use the `index` method: `mylist.index(3)` returns the index of the value `3` in the list `mylist`

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that. But how then would I be able to check if index(3) was one of three indexes or something like in my question?

Comment: Well, you'd need to check each of the three lists in turn, `index` will raise a `ValueError` exception if the value you are looking for isn't in that particular list.

Comment: You mean make sure th 1 is in listoflists?

Comment: Yes, so when the output says "1 is in list 1" that means in the list at index 1, or as you said in the question "the second row".

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,list in enumerate(list_of_lists, 1):
    if 1 in list:
        if i == 1:
            "it is in the first list"
        elif i == 2:
            "it is in the second list"
        ...
```

This is a basic implementation. You would want to parameterize this but I'm not sure exactly what your inputs would be.